# Finding All occurrences of a string in a vector (grep(), which() functions don't quite work)

Tags: r, grepl

I have this [spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gT1ONA2uNpfVeNo0QW6kOJD6A2PgTNTL/view?usp=sharing) and want to see how often the string "Drake" appears.

For example, some rows say "Drake, Kendrick Lamar, Post Malone" , but they're not being counted with the code I have:

```
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Gabriel/Documents/responses.csv", header = TRUE)

artist <- data$artists
grep("Drake$", artist)

artistcount <- which('Drake' == artist)
artistcount
```

the results I get from `grep()` or `which()` are both

```
# 7 47 71
```

I want ALL rows where "Drake" appears. This code shows me which rows had "Drake" as the ONLY string. It should be way more than just 3 rows.
I appreciate any feedback.

Here's an example of the data in the "artists" column:

[image]

Comment: Can you paste a sample of your data in the body of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the filter function from dplyr and str_detech from stringr.

```
 library(stringr)
 library(dplyr)
 data <- read.csv(choose.files())
 drake <- data %>%
   filter(str_detect(artists, "Drake"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to create a copy of the spread sheet, so I also added `drake$artists` to get the new vector I needed.